# why does this simple Hydra command not work?

Tags: unix, cmd, hydra

I'm trying to get the hang of hydra.

When I do this to test against my ftp site, it works.  I'm hitting my own ftp site (ex. www.mysite.com) with the correct username and password (ex. username1 and password1):

```
./hydra -l username1 -p password1 -vV -f www.mysite.com ftp
Hydra v7.4.1 (c)2012 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - for legal purposes only

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2012-12-29 21:06:20
[VERBOSE] More tasks defined than login/pass pairs exist. Tasks reduced to 1.
[DATA] 1 task, 1 server, 1 login try (l:1/p:1), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking service ftp on port 21
[VERBOSE] Resolving addresses ... done
[ATTEMPT] target www.mysite.com - login "username1" - pass "password1" - 1 of 1 [child 0]
[21][ftp] host: 200.200.240.240   login: username1   password: password1
[STATUS] attack finished for www.mysite.com (valid pair found)
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 1 valid password found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2012-12-29 21:06:21
```

However, when I do this to test a public basic authentication test page (`http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php`) with the correct username and password (`test` and `test`), hydra just stops with a 'Resolving address ... done' message.

```
./hydra -l test -p test -vV -f browserspy.dk http-get /password-ok.php
Hydra v7.4.1 (c)2012 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - for legal purposes only

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2012-12-29 21:02:58
[VERBOSE] More tasks defined than login/pass pairs exist. Tasks reduced to 1.
[DATA] 1 task, 1 server, 1 login try (l:1/p:1), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking service http-get on port 80
[VERBOSE] Resolving addresses ... done
```

The hydra process just seems to die here and I'm returned to the command prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just tried, and worked for me like a charm !!

Comment: @lcarus3 Weird -- can you post your command and your full output?   I must be doing something really simple incorrectly -- or you can email to me rhume55 @ gmail.com -- thanks!

Comment: I tried exactly same command like mentioned above. dropped you mail anyway !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, its a bug in hydra which affects the modes `http-get`, `http-head` and irc. Downgrade to v7.3 or wait for v7.5 which will fix this issue.

Comment: this problem still persists in 8 >